# How to define a hasMany relationship to multiple classes?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel, let's say I want to have a Mission with different MissionObjectives, each MissionObjective has it's own model. I have *Mission*, *CheckboxObjective*, *RadioObjetive* and *SpinnerObjective*. I need to connect the Objectives to the Mission, but I don't want to use a different method for each Objective, I want them all in one method. I tried polymorphic relations but they just don't seem to work for this. I would need a Many-to-One, sort of, which doesn't exist.

This is what I want:

Mission class:

```
public function objectives() {
    return *All objectives*;
}
```

Objective classes:

```
public function mission() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Mission');
}
```

Comment: If each of your objective tables have the same table structure (they might not, but if they do), you could create a table for all of the objectives and then have a new column which specifies what type of objective it is. That way you could simply use a `hasMany` on a single `objective model`. Again this may not be applicable to your question depending on your table structures, but I thought I would throw it out as an alternative in the off-chance that it might be.

Comment: Thanks @SawyerClever this would have probably been a good solution in a lot of cases, but each of the Objectives has very different columns. The RadioObjective even has a RadioObjectiveOption as a hasMany relation. If you know a way to integrate this though, please let me know!

Comment: I'm surprised a Polymorphic relationship wouldn't work for this, since that is the main point of that type of relationship; adapting a single model to many other models via the same relationship method. And a `many-to-one` is simply the inverse of a `one-to-many`. Are you able to provide a base database diagram of the tables you're trying to connect? I get the concept you're going for, but a visualization (or at the very lease the linkable columns in each of the tables) would go a long way to helping solve this issue.

Comment: Yeah @TimLewis I will edit my post with a diagram of tables.

Comment: You'd need a `objectives` method in your `Mission` class which returns something like this `$this->hasMany([MainObjective::class, SecondaryObjective::class]);` so you get a collection containing both types(or more)  - sadly this doesnt exist. I'd love to see a solution for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 ways to do this. Both do the job, neither one is perfect.

#### Overview

1. Missions which have multiple `*Objective`

   > `Mission` (1:n) `*Objective` - [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

   - `Mission` hasMany `*Objective`
   - `Objective`(Abstract) belongsTo `Mission`
   - `*Objective` extends `Objective`

---

2. Missions which have multiple `Objective` which in turn each can be of kind `*Objective` (intermediate layer)

   > `Mission` (1:n) `Objective` - [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

   > `Objective` (1:1) `*Objective` - [one-to-one (polymorphic)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations)

   - `Mission` hasMany `Objective`
   - `Objective` morphTo `*Objective`
   - `*Objective` extends `Objective`

You'd use 2 only if you need an itermediate layer if you want to inherit common attributes for `*Objective` from `Objective` - which totally makes sense, since they all at least share `mission_id`.

You won't be able to get inherited attributes by `*Objective` out of the box, because the model for any `*Objective` is bound to a specific table, hence it cant reach the attributes of the inherited `Objective` class. There is a module for this though: [parental](https://github.com/calebporzio/parental)

**edit:** Nevermind, parental only supports STI(Single Table Inheritance) which means we can have multiple models referring the same table.

---

### Solution 1

Tables

```
missions
  id - int

*_objectives (e.g. main_objectives)
  id - int
  mission_id - int
```

Models

```
class Mission extends Model
{
    const OBJECTIVE_TYPES = [
        MainObjective::class,
        // ...
    ];
    
    public function __get($name)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'objectives':
                $objectives = new Collection();
                foreach (static::OBJECTIVE_TYPES as $objectiveType) {
                    $objectives = $objectives->concat($this->hasMany($objectiveType)->get()->all());
                }
                return $objectives;

            default:
                return parent::__get($name);
        }
    }
}

abstract class Objective extends Model
{
    public function mission() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Mission::class, 'mission_id', 'id');
    }
}

class MainObjective extends Objective
{
}
```

Example

```
$mission = Mission::find(1);
foreach ($mission->objectives as $objective) {
    echo 'Class: ' . get_class($objective) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output (In case we have 2 MainObjectives and 1 SecondaryObjective)

```
Class: App\Models\MainObjective
Class: App\Models\MainObjective
Class: App\Models\SecondaryObjective
```

---

### Solution 2

Tables

```
missions
  id - int

objectives
  id - int
  mission_id - int
  objectiveable_type - string
  objectiveable_id - int

*_objectives (e.g.: main_objectives)
  id - int
```

`objectiveable_id` refers the `id` of the table used by the model in `objectiveable_type`.
`objectiveable_type` has to be fully qualified. Example: `App\Models\MainObjective`

Models

```
class Mission extends Model
{
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name === 'objectives') {
            return new Collection(array_map(function ($objective) {
                return $objective->objectiveable;
            }, $this->hasMany(Objective::class)->get()->all()));
        }

        return parent::__get($name);
    }
}

class Objective extends Model
{
    public function objectiveable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    protected function _mission() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Mission::class, 'mission_id', 'id');
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'mission':
                return $this->morphMany(Objective::class, 'objectiveable')->get()->first()->_mission;

            default:
                return parent::__get($name);
        }
    }
}

class MainObjective extends Objective
{
}
```

Example

```
$mission = Mission::find(1);
foreach ($mission->objectives as $objective) {
    echo 'Class: ' . get_class($objective) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output (In case we have 2 MainObjectives and 1 SecondaryObjective)

```
Class: App\Models\MainObjective
Class: App\Models\MainObjective
Class: App\Models\SecondaryObjective
```

Pretty much the same as in the first solution. The big difference here are the attributes. you won't be able to access the attributes of `Objective` of `MainObjective` without extending this further.

---

@Laravel/Eloquent

PLEASE make this easy - my head hurts.

Comment: Thanks for your very extensive answer! I will try this out soon and get back to you!

Comment: I used Solution 1, it works perfectly. Thank you so much! This has really saved me a lot of time.